# How to get HttpRoute List from existing ConnectionPool in HttpComponents - 4.2.2 API

Tags: httpconnection, apache-httpcomponents

I am using HttpComponents 4.2.2 library for Http communication in my web application. HttpClient is used as a Singleton with PoolingClientConnectionManager as its connection manager. Client can initialize the  connections as HttpRoute in PoolingClientConnectionManager by providing host and port. The idea being if a client wants, it can add multiple HttpRoute(s) to the connection pool and initialize connections for those route(s) (restricted by MaxConnectionsPerRoute and TotalMaxConnections settings).

Now my question is, when i receive a request to add a route in the connectionpool, how do i figure out from the connection pool/httpclient api, that if there exists connections initialized for that route already in connectionpool ?

A way of working round is to maintain a list/map of routes already initialized separately for cross checking or lookup, but I am looking for a httpcomponents api support for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PoolingClientConnectionManager#getStats(HttpRoute)?

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html#getStats%28org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute%29